# Open port on Ubuntu Dektop not accessible out of machine

Tags: linux, port

I have opened 9591 port with 0 0.0.0.0:9591 on Ubuntu Dektop machine,

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 9591
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9591            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

curl call with :9591/api for the same with  localhost, 127.0.0.1 is working fine within the machine. Even if i try with IP address, curl works fine within the machine.

ssh to host Ubuntu Desktop machine also working fine within the network.

```
$ curl -vvv http://<IP>:9591/
*   Trying <IP>:9591...
* Connected to <IP> (<IP>) port 9591 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: <IP>:9591
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.18
< Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2023 13:50:39 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 58
< Content-Type: application/json
<
* Closing connection 0
request received.
```

When curl call with :9591/api tried from outside machine within the network, it fails as below -

```
$  curl -vvv http://<IP>:9591/
*   Trying <IP>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to <IP> port 9591 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to <IP> port 9591: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <IP> port 9591: Connection timed out
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Firewall installed? If yes, which and how is it configured?

Comment: `it fails` - how specifically

Comment: @JaromandaX i have updated the question with curl verbose log.  please suggest

Comment: It might be the firewall issue coz this is new machine with Ubuntu 22.04 i have set all things default. how to check for firewall options, as i have full access to machine. Please suggest. @Panki

Comment: @Panki thanks little R&D with firewall settings and stumbled upon with 

$ sudo ufw allow 9591

worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ufw, allow the port for external access -

```
$ sudo ufw allow 9591
```